# YUI minifier is stripping out whitespace from calc()

Tags: css, minify, yui

YUI is stripping out whitespace between % and px like this

```
height: calc(100% + 30px)
```

Rules don't work without them.
[image: ok/not good]

How I can resolve this problem, if I need to use only this minifier?

Comment: Definitely time to move on to a modern, supported minifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this workaround for this:

```
height: calc(100% - -30px);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
height: calc(100%*1 + 30px)
```

The "times 1" prevents the collapse of the space. At least it does with AjaxMin.